# Tkinter : trying to return value from a button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have no idea of how to solve my problem i have a code that looks like this:

```
def f(x):
    x=x.get()
    y=x**2
    z=x-1

Mylist=[]
x=Entry(master)
cmd=lambda x=x : f(x)
Button(master, text="Ok", command=cmd).pack()
```

What i want to do is something like

```
Mylist.append([y,z])
```

In order to use my results somewhere else in my program

Also i know that i could use a class but teachers don't want us to use class for that project...

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `append(f(x))` in `lambda` and `return [y,z]` in `f(x)`. And you have to convert string from `Entry` into `int` or `float`.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def f(x):
    x = int(x.get()) # convert string to int (or float)
    y = x**2
    z = x-1
    return [y, z]

# --- main ---

my_list = []

master = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(master)
e.pack()

cmd = lambda x=e:my_list.append(f(x))

tk.Button(master, text="Ok", command=cmd).pack()

master.mainloop()

print(my_list)
```

You can convert `x` in lambda and then `f(x)` could do only math calculations

EDIT: corrected version as @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen noted in the comment.

```
def f(x):
    return [x**2, x-1]

#cmd = lambda x=int(e.get()):my_list.append(f(x)) # wrong version
cmd = lambda:my_list.append(f(int(e.get()))) # correect version
```

Comment: no you can't actually do `lambda x=int(e.get())` since it is executing the default value for `x` at definition time, you would need to do `lambda x=e:my_list.append(f(int(e.get())))` but I'm not sure lambda is useful at this point, I'd just put it in a one-two line function.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen you are right, I forgot this and I didn't checked this code.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of attaching a command to a button is to implement the answer to the question "what do I want to happen when I click the button?". In your case, the answer is "I want it to a) get the value from an entry widget, b) calculate a new value, and c) append it to a list".

So, write a function that does that, and then call that function from your button. In this case you don't need lambda since you have a 1:1 relationship between the button and entry widget. There's nothing wrong with lambda per se, but in this case it adds complexity without providing any value so I recommend not using it. By *not* using lambda, the code will be easier to debug and maintain over time since it's hard to set breakpoints or add additional functionality inside a lambda.

For example:

```
def f(x):
    y=x**2
    z=x-1

def do_calculation():
    x_value = float(x.get())
    result = f(x_value)
    my_list.append(result)

...
tk.Button(..., command=do_calculation)
```

Comment: the `global` keyword is only necessary when reassigning a variable (with `=`) so while having it there clearly states to a reader that `my_list` is referring to a global variable it isn't strictly necessary to just append to it :)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: yeah, I was a bit sloppy with the use of `global`. I'll fix it. I was thinking it was good to mark it as global so that the code is a bit more obvious, even though `global` isn't strictly necessary. Though, if I use it, I should have used it for `x` too.

Answer (score 0):

You know clicking the button will execute `cmd`, so put whatever you want done (including appending to a list) in there.  Note that this would mean either changing `cmd` to not be a `lambda`, or adding this functionality to `f` (or something even more esoteric).